# How i will inner join with condition in eager loading by laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

```
    enter code here 
                 $wo=Warehouse_other_receive_detail::with('item_info','item_info.product_sub_group')
                ->where('item_info.product_sub_group->sub_group_id', 2)
                ->get();


                 $wo = Warehouse_other_receive_detail::with(['item_info'=>function( $q){
                $q->getQuery()->has('product_sub_group')->where('sub_group_id', 2);
                     }])
                ->get();
```

//but second code is not inner join  i want to first one solve
//How i will access in with function model specific column in main model ----solve this ->>

Comment: try this `->where('item_info.product_sub_group.sub_group_id', 2)`

Comment: $wo=Warehouse_other_receive_detail::with('item_info','item_info.product_sub_group')->where('item_info.product_sub_group.sub_group_id', 2)-get();    already i tried this but it is not work ..

Answer (score 0):

Use whereHas instead of where.You can accomplish what you want with the whereHas method which will perform a query on the relation:

```
$wo = Warehouse_other_receive_detail::with('item_info')->whereHas('item_info', function ($query){
    $query->where('sub_group_id',2);
})->get();
```

Comment: But I want where condition before get function  such as $wo = Warehouse_other_receive_detail::with('item_info')->where('sub_group_id',2)->get();